# Python How to supress showing Error in user created function before the function is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have imported a user created file into my main code but an error in imported file is being displayed before. How can I suppress that error and display it only when the function is called

Importing file and its function :

```
import userValidation

NameString = input("Enter your name : ")
```

I have called `user_validation` function later in the code :

user_validation(names)

`user_validation()` has some error which I know and is being displayed just after the code start running.

I want to suppress the error till the time user_validation is called.How can i do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use exception handling appropriately.

```
try:

#code with exception

except:

#handle it here
```

In the `except` part you may use `pass` to just move on if no action is required or use `raise` to handle it in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology is a bit confusing, and in particular you aren't telling us the nature of the error (syntax, function definition, etc).

When you do:

```
import userValidation
```

The code in that module is run - up to the `if __name__ =='__main__':` block.  Normally that code will contain other imports and a set of function and class definitions.  That `if` block is supposed to contain variable definitions and function calls that will be used in a stand alone script call.

With proper separation, the only things that will be run during the import are the function and class definitions.  The functions don't have to run correctly, they just have to have a valid syntax.

You should be able to wrap the import in a try/except block

```
try:
   import userValidation
except ImportError:    # or other error type
   userValidation = None
```

Typically this structure is used to import modules that might not be present on the system.  I'm not sure what errors you get if there is a syntax or other error in the imported file.  But keep in mind that if there is an error, that module (or any of its functions) will not be available for latter use.

If this answer isn't enough, you need to describe the errors, maybe even give us a working (or not) example.